# "Warning: Native component for <component> does not exist" in new React Native component

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a simple React Native module that wraps a native iOS component (the [Stripe SDK](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios)).  I followed the [instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html) and based my code on an existing component which works fine, [react-native-facebook-login](https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login).

Whenever I attempt to include my component in React Native, I get this mysterious warning:

`Warning: Native component for "RCTStripe" does not exist`

The component does exist. I created an iOS library for it, with `RCTStripeManager.m/h`, which inherits from `RCTViewManager`. `RCTStripe` inherits from `RCTView` and is init'ed and returned by the manager, etc. All of this is modeled on another module which works perfectly.

What's going on?

Here's some sample code:

RCTStripeManager.h

```
#import "RCTViewManager.h"

@interface RCTStripeManager : RCTViewManager

@end
```

RCTStripeManager.m

```
#import "RCTBridge.h"
#import "RCTEventDispatcher.h"
#import "RCTLog.h"

#import "RCTStripe.h"
#import "RCTStripeManager.h"

@implementation RCTStripeManager
{
    RCTStripe *_stripe;
}

@synthesize bridge = _bridge;

- (UIView *)view
{
    _stripe = [[RCTStripe alloc] init];
    return _stripe;
}

- (dispatch_queue_t)methodQueue
{
    return dispatch_get_main_queue();
}

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

@end
```

RCTStripe.h

```
#import "RCTView.h"

@interface RCTStripe : RCTView

@end
```

RCTStripe.m

```
#import <Stripe/Stripe.h>

#import "RCTStripe.h"
#import "RCTLog.h"

@implementation RCTStripe

- (id)init
{
  if ((self = [super init])) {
      // init code here
      UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
      [myLabel setText:@"Hello world"];
      [self addSubview:myLabel];
  }

  return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    RCTAssert(self.subviews.count == 1, @"we should only have exactly one subview");
}

- (void)insertReactSubview:(UIView *)view atIndex:(NSInteger)atIndex
{
    RCTLogError(@"FBLoginButton does not support subviews");
    return;
}

- (void)removeReactSubview:(UIView *)subview
{
    RCTLogError(@"FBLoginButton does not support subviews");
    return;
}

- (NSArray *)reactSubviews
{
    return @[];
}

@end
```

index.ios.js

```
var React = require('react-native');
var {
  StyleSheet,
  NativeModules,
  requireNativeComponent,
  NativeMethodsMixin,
} = React;

var { StripeManager } = NativeModules;

var SuperStripe = React.createClass({

  mixins: [NativeMethodsMixin],

  render: function() {
    var props = {
      ...this.props,
      style: ([styles.base, this.props.style]),
    };

    return <RCTStripe {...props} />
  },
});

var RCTStripe = requireNativeComponent('RCTStripe', SuperStripe);

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  base: {
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
  },
});

module.exports = SuperStripe;
```

Full code is in https://github.com/lrettig/react-native-stripe. Inside the `example/` directory, run `npm install` and `npm start`, then open `example/ios/example.xcodeproj` and run it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out this was happening because I started with an existing module with a different name, and I renamed the Xcode project.  When I renamed the Xcode project, for some reason it removed the module project (`RCTStripe`) from the "Link Binary with Libraries" section of the build phases for the parent (sample) project, so the code wasn't being run at all.  Adding it back fixed this.

Comment: Can you specify more precisely the steps you took to fix this ? I'm confused. Did you link something back using react-native link ?

Answer (score 0):

Another scenario this error occurs is when installing a new native package.

Make sure to:

- run yarn: **yarn install**
- run cocoapods: **pod install** in `/ios` folder
- build the app again through XCode/Android Studio or `yarn start` command.